# How do I know that a capacitor is real or ideal given admittance value?

Tags: capacitor

I stumbled upon this exercise in my course and I was wondering how to do it.

I know that in:

-REAL capacitors: P ≠ 0 , and φ  ≠ -pi/2

-IDEAL capacitors: C = constant, and R = 0.

My admittance is given like this:

Y = 1 + j2 [S]

I also know that Y = G -jB. That would mean in my case that G = 1 and B = -2. Any ideas on how to continue this?

Comment: What do you know about the admittance - or impedance - of ideal capacitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal capacitor has zero series resistance, and infinite parallel resistance. It's impedance is imaginary, and it's admittance is imaginary. So if there is any real part, i.e. G is not zero, the capacitor is not ideal.